# Using "npm publish" to publish a zip file to private registry

Tags: npm, artifactory, npm-publish

I have a zip file which is basically an archive of a production build generated by webpack. How can I use "npm publish" to publish this zip file to my Artifactory?

```
npm publish mybuild-0.0.1.zip --registry https://artifactory.com/path/path
```

The above is giving me an error saying `mybuild-0.0.1.zip@latest` doesn't exist.

Also, mybuild.0.0.1.zip, currently doesn't have a package.json. Should it have one?

Answer (score 1):

package.json is essential for all npm artifacts. https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json